# How to print java.sql.connection number?

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I want to print java.sql.connection objects number, I want to know which application thread uses which connection object. It seems https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/ provides the connection number, but I dont know if I can get through some standard library?

I am using mysql database.

Comment: "Connection Number" is not a universally recognized attribute.  From the docs it appears to be related to connection pooling, but in general the phrase "Connection Number" doesn't have a well-known definition.

Comment: It says _"SQL connection number information is generated"_ which makes me think that log4jdbc itself assigns a number to its connection proxies.